# Can I close my question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Will Stack Overflow have a close question option once I create a question?

Comment: FYI, close votes cannot be undone. Please be sure you really want to close before you vote. Closing here does not mean "my question has been answered"; see [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stackoverflow-how-do-they-work).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the FAQ:

> 250    Vote to close, reopen, or
>   migrate your questions

So you need 250 rep for that.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to **Close** or **Delete** your question - but subject to some reputation requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also mark the question as answered to indicate that you're satisfied with an answer.